# Touching all hard links to a file in Vim

Tags: vim

How do I execute touch on all hard links to the file when saving a file?

I have a program that monitors the directory for a change, but some files have hard links on another directories, and it's not noticed if it's edited there.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I execute touch on all hard links to the file when saving a file?

I don't know. But ...

> I have a program that monitors the directory for a change, but some files have hard links on another directories, and it's not noticed if it's edited there.

So far as I can tell, tools like [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) can watch an arbitrary list of files, they don't have to all be in one directory.

> `--fromfile`  Read filenames to watch or exclude from a file, one filename per line. If filenames begin with @ they are excluded as
>   described above. If  is '-', filenames are read from standard
>   input. Use this option if you need to watch too many files to pass in
>   as command line arguments.

Therefore you might be able to define the set of monitored files by adding their pathnames to a text file rather than by making hard-links to them.